# ekiga as an asterisk client

Tags: linux, networking, asterisk, voip, ekiga

is [this the typical Asterisk topology](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Ekiga_as_an_Asterisk_client)?

[image: ekiga/asterisk]

On my home system, I have the Asterisk server, `tleilax`, and the client, `doge`, connecting into my router -- so that they're both on the same network.  The IP addresses are:

router    192.168.1.1

tleilax   192.168.1.2

doge      192.168.1.x (usually 3)

Based on the above image, I don't quite understand what the topology should look like.  What if you have multiple clients?  They can't all connect to `tleilax` unless you put in a ton of NIC's!

Here you see multiple clients connected to an Asterisk box:

[image: hard phones]

but no mention of a switch...

Pardon, if it's in the [definitive guide](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/), I missed it.  (I have the 4th ed.)

This diagram:

[image: sip trapezoid]

well useful, doesn't help me to understand the network topology of a simple setup, but with multiple clients..

Comment: I'm considering a [simple switch](http://us.dlink.com/products/connect/5-port-gigabit-desktop-switch/) so that `doge` and other pc's can connect to `tleilax`...but I suppose `tleilax` will need another NIC, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These images show `logical` topology not physical one.

### Image 1

It does not mean you have to get many NICs if you want many client. The line symbolizes LAN there. So in fact your physical topology will include a switch, to which all the clients, and the asterisk box would be connected.

### Image 2

This show the *basic* mode of operation. SIP protocol is used **only for signalling**. Voice is transmitted by RTP protocol **directly** between the clients (or in some scenarios through an asterisk, which helps in NAT traversal).

The image below shows a typical SIP flow, you can see SIP protocol in action but when the session is established, media channel (RTP) goes directly between the clients.

[image]

### Image 3 ##

This is basically the same as Image 2 but instead of 1 proxy, here every client has its own SIP proxy. This is a typical situation where each of the users is in a different VoIP provider.

### Summing up

If you want a simple topology with a SIP Registry server and Proxy, then you can have one Asterisk, switch and computers in one LAN.

PS: Mind that **the most basic** SIP topology is with clients alone, which can communicate to each other directly with SIP. No proxy, no registry needed.